# CsvHelper Command parameter into index file

Tags: csvhelper

This is my current datamap how do I pass command line argument to the index as the csv file could change. I am using CommandLineParse to do my console command line

```
public class CSVData
{

    public string? FName { get; set; }
    public string? LName { get; set; }
}

public sealed class DataMap : ClassMap<CSVData>
{
    public DataMap()
    {

        Map(m => m.FName).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.LName).Index(1);

    }
}
```

This is my command file.

```
using CommandLine;

namespace CommandLineParsing
{
    public class CommandLineOptions
    {
        [Option(shortName: 'f', longName: "firstName", Required = true)]
        public int firstName{ get; set; }

        [Option(shortName: 'l', longName: "lastName", Required = true)]
        public int lastName{ get; set; }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the values to the `ClassMap` constructor.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("Blade,Runner"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(new DataMap(1,0));
        
        var records = csv.GetRecords<CSVData>().Dump();
    }
}

public class CSVData
{
    public string? FName { get; set; }
    public string? LName { get; set; }
}

public sealed class DataMap : ClassMap<CSVData>
{
    public DataMap(int fname, int lname)
    {

        Map(m => m.FName).Index(fname);
        Map(m => m.LName).Index(lname);

    }
}
```